# Math.round return NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to update the x and y values to crop an image via Ajax and PHP.

This code opens a dialog window with an image on click a button. Works fine but Firebug shows NaN post variables. How can I get the correct values? I have tried parseFloat() and parseInt() to return a number variable.

```
jQuery(function($) {

    jQuery('#jc-hidden-image').Jcrop({
        onChange: showCoords,
        onSelect: showCoords
    });

});

function showCoords(c) {
    jQuery('#x1').val(c.x);
    jQuery('#y1').val(c.y);
    jQuery('#x2').val(c.x2);
    jQuery('#y2').val(c.y2);
    jQuery('#w').val(c.w);
    jQuery('#h').val(c.h);
};
jQuery(function($) {

    $('#jc-dyn-btn').click(function() {
        var jcrop_api;
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var rel = $(this).attr('data-rel');
        var value = $(this).attr('data-value');
        var mainImage = rel + '/' + id;
        var x, y, w, h;
        x = Math.round($('#x1').val());
        y = Math.round($('#y1').val());
        w = Math.round($('#w').val());
        h = Math.round($('#h').val());
        $("
    img.jc - hidden - image ").attr("
    src ", mainImage);
        var $dialog = $(" < div > < div id = \"jc-dialog\ class=\"jc-dialog\"><img class=\"jc-hidden-image\" src=\"" + mainImage + "\" /><form id=\"coords\" class=\"coords\"><label>X1<input type=\"text\" size=\"4\" id=\"x1\" name=\"x1\" /></label><label>Y1 <input type=\"text\" size=\"4\" id=\"y1\" name=\"y1\" /></label><label>X2 <input type=\"text\" size=\"4\" id=\"x2\" name=\"x2\" /></label><label>Y2 <input type=\"text\" size=\"4\" id=\"y2\" name=\"y2\" /></label><label>W <input type=\"text\" size=\"4\" id=\"w\" name=\"w\" /></label><label>H <input type=\"text\" size=\"4\" id=\"h\" name=\"h\" /></label></form></div>");

        $dialog.find('img').Jcrop({
            onChange: showCoords,
            onSelect: showCoords
        }, function() {
            jcrop_api = this;
            jcrop_api.animateTo([259, 81, 469, 304]);
            $dialog.dialog({
                modal: true,
                title: 'Jcrop in jQuery-ui Dialog (Dynamic)',
                close: function() {
                    $dialog.remove();
                },
                width: jcrop_api.getBounds()[0] + 34,
                resizable: false,
                buttons: {
                    "SAVE": function() {
                        $.ajax({

                            url: "crop.php",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: "x=" + x + "&y=" + y + "&w=" + w + "&h=" + h + "&src=" + mainImage,

                            success: function() {
                                //  $dialog.dialog('close');
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    "CLOSE": function() {
                        $dialog.dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            }) //dialog
        }); //function
        return false;
    }); //clik
}); //jquery​
```

Comment: Not much to go on here.  If Math.round retunrs NaN, what was the input?

Comment: You have several too many whitespaces in your string literals. Also, you wouldn't need to escape every `"` if you'd use apostrophes (`'`) as string delimiters.

Comment: Ok, I will make a revision again. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Try this, use `parseFloat` like

```
Math.round(parseFloat($('#x1').val()));
```

**Update:**

Also make sure you are using right `id`s for the inputs, whether it should be `$('#x1')` or `$('#x')`.
[**Here is an example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ku25C/1/).

Comment: Yes, but in this code doesn´t works and pass NaN values.. strange... Could be am I getting other values? input type=\"text\" size=\"4\" id=\"x1\" name=\"x1\" />

Comment: @user1723670, you are setting value with `jQuery('#x1').val(c.x);`, where is `c.x` came from, is this a real number ?

Comment: var Coords = (function () {
      var x1 = 0,
          y1 = 0,
          x2 = 0,
          y2 = 0,
          ox, oy;});

Comment: @user1723670, Where did you find `c.x` ?

Comment: This is a predetermined function in Jcrop:    function showCoords(c)
   {
    jQuery('#x1').val(c.x);
    jQuery('#y1').val(c.y);
    jQuery('#x2').val(c.x2);
    jQuery('#y2').val(c.y2);
    jQuery('#w').val(c.w);
    jQuery('#h').val(c.h);
    
   };

Comment: http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=handler  is tehe example working but without sending vars

Comment: mmm... I think could be difficult.. Maybe for some reason am I getting the values from this lines? `var mainImage = id;
  var x, y, w, h;` and not from here? `<input type=\"text\" value=\"\" size=\"4\" id=\"x1\" name=\"x1\" />`

Comment: **Sheikh Heera** Thanks. No problem. I will make a revision again.

Comment: @user1723670, I've made an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ku25C/). Make sure `$('#x1')` is not `$('#x')`.

Comment: Works perfect. You are right. thousand of excuses. Thanks for help me to learn. Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to use `parseFloat`. Change the statements to:

```
x = Math.round( parseFloat($('#x1').val()) );
y = Math.round( parseFloat($('#y1').val()) );
w = Math.round( parseFloat($('#w').val()) );
h = Math.round( parseFloat($('#h').val()) );
```

Comment: Yes, but in this code doesn´t works and pass NaN values.. strange... Could be am I getting other values? input type=\"text\" size=\"4\" id=\"x1\" name=\"x1\" />